# How to reset the completion in wildmenu?

Tags: vim

In vim when you complete something (in insert mode) you can "reset" the completion to what you initially typed with CTRL-E. However , in wildmenu that doesn't work. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Does selecting the first completion and then hitting left do what you want?

It seems that <kbd>Tab</kbd> (wildchar) and a direction allows you to go to the beginning or end of the completion list. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> to go to the beginning or <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd> to select the end. So your shortcut would be <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> (select the first item and then go back one).

Unfortunately, `cmap <C-e> <Tab><Right><Left>` just inserts a tab.

My wild settings:

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest:full
set wildchar=<Tab>    " (default)
```

Comment: Almost. That's the behavior I would like to have but I use the wildmenu too. My set up is wildmode=longest:full,full. Therefor when I hit <tab> a second time, it doesn't exit from the wildmode, as you, but start the wildmenu.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably interested in the `'wildmode'` setting. Probably you want :

```
set wildmode=list:longest,full
```

See `:help 'wildmode'` for more explanations. Also have a look at `:help cmdline-completion` for more insight.

Comment: My problem is not how to complete but to "cancel" the completion , as the C-E key do (in :help cmdline-completion). I just want an equivalent for the wildmode.